# WPF: Open Calendar like DatePicker in popup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and want to use a `Calender` in one cell. I know a way to make the `Calender` look like a MonthPicker, that is why I chose this class.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EinsatzAb, StringFormat=d}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Calendar DisplayMode="Year" SelectedDate="{Binding EinsatzAb}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The problem is that the `Calendar` is not opened in a popup but in the DataGrid cell.

[image: datagrid]

How to make it open in a popup like DatePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put it in a `Popup` element:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Popup IsOpen="True">
            <Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding EinsatzAb}" />
        </Popup>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```